# Jinja2 Default Page Title

Tags: python, templates, flask, jinja2

I'm attempting to set a default page title for all pages in a Flask application.

I want to insert this into the default layout template. I have a site name in my settings.

```
<title>{{title}}</title}}
```

The problem is, I cannot seem to import the site name from the settings to the layout template.

```
<title>{{settings.SETTING}}</title}}
```

and similar variations do not work.

Is there an easy way to do this; I don't want to have to set the title with every action in my controller, and the logical way is go from my settings to the template. I just don't see a way right now, any input appreciated.

edit:

I'd prefer not to write an extension, I see another part of my app is using an extension to pull variables into the template, but writing an entire extension is a bit beyond my time investment at the time.

edit:

```
def page_title(title):
    return settings.SITE_NAME

app.jinja_env.filters['page_title'] = page_title
```

in template:

```
{{ title | page_title}}
```

which is something close, i want to set title OR override with a default and that is a first step that works

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a block:

```
<title>{% block title %}{{ settings.SETTING }}{% endblock %}</title>
```

Then you can simply override that block in a template inheriting from your base template if you want to change the title.

```
{% block title %}your custom title{% endblock %}
```

Comment: ok that is a good start, and I like this more than my own solution, but I have a problem in that 'settings' isn't accessible and creates an error i.e. my original problem in that I'm not able to read from settings-->template.

Comment: Ah, I'd simply use app.config for it which is available as `config` in templates. Otherwise you need to add `settings` to your template context: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/#context-processors

Comment: It does come up if I use {{ config['NAME'] }} and this works so I'm going with this for now.

Comment: `{{ config.NAME }}` would be nicer